# [ERROR][Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306?

Tags: mysql

[image]

[image]

When i type mysqld --console(picture 1) 
I get the error that I have another mysql server running on port 3306 (picture 2)

How can I find and delete the other mysql running on port 3306?(from command line)

Comment: sudo netstat -peanut | grep ":3306 "

Comment: the last column is PID/Program name, so to kill the program use `kill PID` or `kill -9 PID`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First identify the PID of the process using port 3306

```
netstat -aon
```

Stop the task by

```
taskkill /pid 1234 /f
```

Replace 1234 with the PID of port 3306

Answer (score 0):

if you are having this problem yet and it is not resolved then you can just change the poet in which your MySQL server is currently running on...I will explain by picture in link below....

I am sorry that I cant add the pictures directly to the post since I don't meet the criteria but I am sure it will help you by 101%. If it doesn't work then understand that you again have to change the port and use another port value[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0rjl.png)

***1) Click on config of MySQL
2) Change the port from 3306(default) to any other
3) Save the text file
4) It helps and restart the server.***

Comment: Please format your answer properly.